# I Cannot run jar file in kubuntu terminal

Tags: jar, java, ubuntu

I thinks it is some problems in my java installation but i don't know what is the problem and how can i fix it

I can run jar file with openjdk in visual mode but in terminal i cannot run jar files
for example you can see this below

```
root@mohammad-Inspiron-1564:/media/storage/Linux/Freedom# java -jar freedom.jar 
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:110)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81)
        at java.awt.Window.initGC(Window.java:466)
        at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:486)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:218)
        at de.resolution.emsgui.LanguageSelector.showButtonGrid(LanguageSelector.java:27)
        at de.resolution.emsgui.LanguageSelector.<init>(LanguageSelector.java:19)
        at emsgui.main(emsgui.java:46)
```

perhaps i should re-install mu kubuntu :((

thnx
Mohammad

Comment: 1) running as root: Bad :)  2) if you start a Swing application, you need to have the X Windows GUI running on your desktop.  You can start from a GUI terminal ... but you *need* the X GUI.  Or it'll crash.  3) Finally, "root" needs permissions to connect to X

Comment: 1) I think perhaps my problem can solved with login as root
2) I have already X windows GUI running : because I have gui running
3) I should see it ;-)
4) THNX

Comment: Q: Have you tried `xhost +`: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=296443

Comment: oh no because oracle blocked IPs from my country and now i have no vpn connection ;-)

I have create a new user and run it with this user previlages and it is OK
Now I can run it but i don't know is it correct to have this problem under root or not 
:-p

AGAIN THANKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you that it cannot connect to the X11 window server. The program in the JAR file uses Swing and needs some way to display the GUI it creates. If you have X11 installed, you can start it from the command-line by typing `startx`. Otherwise you need to install it or some other system that will allow you to run a Swing-based program.

Comment: 1) Thanks for your answer
2) I have stop and start gui with startx but still I have the problem